# Hiring General Contractor Or Help From Family-friend Investor Who Flips Homes

Tags: remodeling, contractors

My wife and I purchased a home, it is in good shape structurally but we want do some work to it. We are hiring an architect. But the GC is a bit more complicated. I intended to hire a GC for the whole project. But, my wife wants to leverage a childhood friend who is not a GC but remodels properties and flips them. He uses a GC who only signs permit requests only, who charges 10% of associated work value. I would appreciate any insights or any red flags that I need to watch out for.

*Backstory*

Wife has a childhood friend who is now a successful businessman. He owns a few high-end retail stores in malls. Since the stores no longer occupy much of his time, he also flips homes with the subcontractors who built his stores. In the last two years he did 30 properties. He is even remodeling his own new home about 5 minutes from ours, and it is very nice work. He offered to help us by helping plan, coordinate the project and make his trusted subcontractor team available for us. He is not asking for any compensation. The backstory is that when he was a teenager, my mother in law took care of him for a few years as his family was going through a rough time. There is a deep connection there. I only recently met him as we just moved to the city that my wife grew up in. Obviously, my wife wants to leverage him and trusts him. I was skeptical at first until I saw the house he was remodeling and we talked more through it.

*Project description*

- We intend to pull permits for everything that requires it.
- New floors throughout home.
- Redo kitchen with custom cabinetry. Requires demolishing one wall and moving some plumbing around.
- We intend to hire a kitchen design company.
- Redo bathrooms.
- Keep layouts the same except for master bathroom.
- Install tankless toilets.
- Create a new bedroom from an large storage closet
- Move wall 3 feet.
- Move HVAC into attic.
- Add new window. Need to move condenser in exterior as it is where window would open.
- Create a new bathroom out of a medium size storage closet
- Replace closets
- Replace interior doors
- Removing decorative columns

*Thoughts*

- Given that I am permitting all the work, I expect build quality is ensured.
- Pro: I avoid the 20% fee on the entire project. I pay 10% on the work requiring permit.
- Timeline slippage due to managing errors may negate some of the cost savings, but I should come out ahead. It's a risk I am ok taking since I am well capitalized for all of this.

*Key Concerns*

- I am not sure how legal is the setup of a GC who only signs permit requests and never steps on property.
- I am not sure what is covered by the GC's insurance that is not covered by the subcontractor insurance itself? Why is it good for the GC to be insured? Do I need that?
- I assume that GCs have people on staff to do the odd-ball work. Like installing the fixtures, lighting, bathroom tub, install interior doors, etc. I am unsure of who picks up this type of work?
- Would insurance companies have an issue with me doing all this work without a GC? I will ask my insurance agent, but I am curious what people here know.

Comment: Permitted work usually requires inspections to past, so you, the GC, or joe down the street should not matter to insurance who does the work and it passes inspections.

Comment: If the GC is not actually setting foot on the property, you are really your own GC. There is nothing wrong with that, as long as local permitting rules allow it. Permits typically cover three issues: general building permits (which are in some places required for "almost everything" and some places "only if you move walls or add on to the outside", etc. - varies a lot) but usually (in my experience, but again may vary by location) *anyone* can get those permits. Electrical and plumbing more often (but not always) require a licensed professional to pull those permits, but your subcontractors

Comment: should be able to do that for you - don't need a paid GC for that. Installing fixtures, lighting, tub, etc. - those are things you may be able to do yourself and/or may be done by your electrical and plumbing subcontractors, depending on the details. So it really comes down to whether you (yourself and/or hiring people) can handle the general work (building walls, drywall, painting, etc.) or want someone else to do it all for a fee. I did my kitchen myself with professional electrician and plumber plus a little non-skilled help from relatives - although the total project scope was much smaller

Comment: than you have described, these kinds of projects *can* be mostly DIY if you have the time and interest in doing so.

Comment: If things go south (quality from subs, etc), who makes that right? The GC paperboy? Your buddy? Understand these issues before you jump into the deep end.

Comment: And build quality is not assured by permitting. Compliance to code (usually) is. The worst quality work imaginable can pass inspection.